# Unable to install packages using pip install in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation

When I try to install packages through pip install command in Python, it shows the error below:

```
Retrying<Retry<total=0, connect = None, read = None, redirect = None>> after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError<'<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000004F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failes',>": /simple/numpy
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy<from versions:>
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

It shows the same error for any package that I try to install.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard error message from `pip` when there is no internet connection. If you do

```
ping google.com
```

you will probably find out that that there is something wrong with your connection. Fix those problems and pip should start working.